# Typescript get key value from Interface

Tags: typescript, generics, types

```js
export interface Cookies {
  Authentication: string;
  Refresh: string;
  DeviceId: string;
}

type key = keyof Cookies
// key is "Authentication" | "Refresh" | "DeviceId"

export const COOKIE_KEYS: Record<key, key> = {
  Authentication: 'Authentication',
  Refresh: 'Refresh',
  DeviceId: 'DeviceId',
};
```

I want to enforce the COOKIE_KEYS, so that each key is equal to value.

Authentication = 'Authentication'

Is there a way to create a key-value lookup from keyof interface?
Perhaps via reflection?

### Update

I solved this problem by using similar solution to C# nameOf.

```
export function nameOf<T>(name: Extract<keyof T, string>): string {
  return name;
}

nameOf<Cookies>('Authentication') // = 'Authentication'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```js
export interface Cookies {
  Authentication: string;
  Refresh: string;
  DeviceId: string;
}

type Keys = keyof Cookies

/**
 * Iterate through every key of Cookies
 * and assign key to value
 */
type Make<T extends string>={
    [P in T]:P
}

type Result = Make<Keys>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.

I end it up by simplify this to,


type CookieMap = {
  [P in keyof Cookies]: P;
};